# ls -l command output

Tags: macos, terminal

This is the output of ls -l command on mac os terminal

```
drwx------@ 47 abhishekkumarjha  staff    1598 Nov 15 00:05 Library
drwx------+  3 abhishekkumarjha  staff     102 Apr  9  2015 Movies
```

What does '@' or '+' symbol signify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the file or directory has extended attributes, the permissions field printed by the -l
>        option is followed by a '@' character.  Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security
>        information (such as an access control list), the permissions field printed by the -l option is followed by a '+' character.

You can find more info on [Apple's developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ls.1.html) and look for **The Long Format**

Comment: I saw that in help manual. Could not understand explanation.  What are extended attributes or security information? can you please elaborate.

Comment: [Extended file attributes](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/pages/extattrs.html) are name/value textual pairs which can be associated with files, to describe them beyond what the standard filesystem attributes provide (e.g. author="John Smith", subject="country landscape")

Comment: While the security info can be used to secure the files beyond the default access control of the system, such as [Access Control List](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) which provides an additional, more flexible permission mechanism for file systems. It is designed to assist UNIX file permissions to give permissions for any user or group to any disc resource.